# String split dosen't work in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a text file containing lines of Strings. which separates String using '$@' symbols.
(xxxx $@ yyyy $@ zzzz)

I want to separate these string. so I tried following code

```
String string = "xxx $@ yyyy $@ zzzz";
String[] parts = string.split("$@");
```

but it does not work.

Any how I create test project and pus '-' insted of '$@' and it works fine.

so how can I separate those Strings? any Suggestions??

Comment: you must escape the $ \\$

Comment: This **must** be a duplicate question... *(Edit: Found the earlier one)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you give `split` defines a regular expression, so any characters special in regular expressions have to be escaped:

```
String[] parts = string.split("\\$@");
```

You escape a special character in a regular expression with a single backslash. To get a single backslash into a string literal in Java, of course, you have to escape it, so you end up with two backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

look at the documentation when something doesnt work as expected: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-
String split takes regular expression as parameter, not plain string. Because of that you need to escape `$` because it is special character denoting end of line. To see all special regex characters check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

In short, this should work:

```
String string = "xxx $@ yyyy $@ zzzz";
String[] parts = string.split("\\$@");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :`string.split("\\$@");`

Answer (score 0):

The reason that isn't working is because the String's split method takes a regular expression as its parameter, not just a String value to split by.

In Java regular expressions, the `$` symbol is a special character that means "end of the line". Splitting by "$@" will most likely never work.

Instead, escape the `$` with a backslash.

```
String[] parts = string.split("\\$@");
```

That should work.